# Program prints unrelated chars

Tags: c, arrays

I wanted to split an array to 2 arrays that the first one contains the lowercased letters of the original array and the second one contains the uppercased letters and from some reason it prints some unrelated chars.

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN 8
int main(void)
{
 char str[] = "SHaddOW";
 char smallStr[LEN], bigStr[LEN]; 
 int i = 0;
 int indexSmall = 0;
 int indexBig = 0;

 for (i = 0; i <= LEN; i++)
 {
  if (str[i] <= 'Z')
  {
   smallStr[indexSmall] = str[i];
   indexSmall++;
  }
  if (str[i] >= 'Z')
  {
   bigStr[indexBig] = str[i];
   indexBig++;
  }
 }

 printf("1: ");
 puts(smallStr);
 printf("2: ");
 puts(bigStr);

 system("PAUSE");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i <= LEN` will exceed the bounds of `str[]` whose maximum index is `6`. It will also break the two target arrays, whose maximum index is `7`.

Comment: Add the line `smallStr[indexSmall] = bigStr[indexBig] = 0` to add the null character

Comment: Please get rid of the [system("PAUSE");](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34522206/721269) before it hurts someone. For all you know, the `PAUSE` command on my computer pauses the cooling system for my nuclear reactor.

Comment: ... It plays havoc with my pacemaker as well

Comment: @WeatherVane Oops, I miscounted OP's characters. He's got seven of them, not eight!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz `system("pause")` is likely to "hurt someone"? Really? There is such a thing as unnecessary exaggeration.

Comment: @asker What is your understanding of what a string is?

Answer (score 2):

Don't define length before you create the string to test.
Create it's length after defining the string to test.

Copy the characters as you encounter them, but as @Ed Heal says you must add a null terminator so that you can print out the two strings (they aren't really strings until they are null terminated).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void)
{
        char str[] = "SHaddOW";
        int len = strlen(str) +1;
        char smallStr[len], bigStr[len];
        char term[] = {'\0'};
        int n, s, b;

        s=0;
        b=0;
        for(n=0; n<len; n++) {
                if(islower(str[n])) {
                        memcpy(smallStr +s,  str +n, 1);
                        s++;
                } else if (isupper(str[n])){
                        memcpy(bigStr +b,  str +n, 1);
                        b++;
                }
        }
        memcpy(smallStr + s, term, 1);
        memcpy(bigStr + b , term, 1 );

        printf("Upper: %s\n", bigStr);
        printf("Lower: %s\n", smallStr);
}
```

Output:

Upper: SHOW
Lower: add

Add this to the if structure (and other code to support it)

```
} else {
        memcpy(anyStr +a, str +n, 1);
        a++;
}
```

then:
char str[] = ".S1H2a3d4d5O6W.";
and:
printf("Anything else: %s\n", anyStr);

returns:
Upper: SHOW
Lower: add
Anything else: .123456.

Comment: This `int len = strlen(str);` ... `char smallStr[len];` makes the array 1 space too small.

Comment: @John Hascall - yes of course - no space for the null terminator if  characters are all upper or all lower.  I will correct it.

Answer (score 2):

A more compact approach with (perhaps) more meaningful variable names:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void ) {
    const char  str[]   = "SHaddOW";
    size_t      len     = strlen(str);    /* better to get actual length */
    char        lowers[len + 1];          /* add one for the nul char */
    char        uppers[len + 1];          /* (see below) */
    int         c;
    int         i       = 0;
    int         n_upper = 0;
    int         n_lower = 0;

    while ((c = str[i++]) != '\0') {
        if (isupper(c)) uppers[n_upper++] = c;    /* no need to reinvent */
        if (islower(c)) lowers[n_lower++] = c;    /* the wheel here */
    }
    uppers[n_upper] = '\0';                  /* the nul char ('\0') marks */
    lowers[n_lower] = '\0';                  /* the end of a C "string" */

    printf("1: %s\n", lowers);
    printf("2: %s\n", uppers);
    return 0;
}
```

### Notes

If you are super concerned about efficiency you could add an `else` before `if (islower...`

Adding `const` means you "promise" the characters in the array won't be changed.

The type `size_t` is an integer type, but may be larger than `int`.  It is the correct type for the return of `strlen()`.  It is defined in `<stdint.h>`.  None the less, using `int` will almost always work *(on most systems a string would have to be 'yooooge' for its length to be bigger than an int can hold)*.

The variable `c` is declared as `int` instead of `char` because `int` is the proper type for the `isXXXXX()` functions *(which are defined in `<ctype.h>`)*.  It is also a good habit to get into because of the parallels between this loop and another common idiom `while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `isupper()` and `islower()` functions. Code would be cleaner. And what if you have some non alpha characters? Your conditions won't work.

```
for (i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
{
    if (islower(str[i]))
    {
        smallStr[indexSmall] = str[i];
        indexSmall++;
    }
    else if (isupper(str[i]))
    {
        bigStr[indexBig] = str[i];
        indexBig++;
    }
}
```

As @Ed Heal mention. To avoid printing rubbish, after for loopt you should add a null characters to arrays.

```
smallStr[indexSmall] = '\0';
bigStr[indexBig] = '\0';
```

Comment: You missing out the nub of the problem - the null character

Comment: You might need another go :-)